# Go Select and multiple cases at once

Tags: concurrency, go

How to adapt the code below to do something when C1 and C2 have been BOTH received
https://gobyexample.com/select

```
import "time"
import "fmt"

func main() {

    c1 := make(chan string)
    c2 := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
        c1 <- "one"
    }()
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
        c2 <- "two"
    }()

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        select {
        case msg1 := <-c1:
            fmt.Println("received", msg1)
        case msg2 := <-c2:
            fmt.Println("received", msg2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It must help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593126/reading-from-multiple-channels-simultaneously-in-golang

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your for loop handles getting both values.

Comment: @JimB I want case msg1 AND msg2 together not one OR another

Comment: @0xAX thanks seems close to what I want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That could be a [pipeline technique, called fan-in](http://blog.golang.org/pipelines#TOC_4.):

> A function can read from multiple inputs and proceed until all are closed by multiplexing the input channels onto a single channel that's closed when all the inputs are closed. This is called fan-in.

```
func merge(cs ...<-chan int) <-chan int {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    out := make(chan string)

    // Start an output goroutine for each input channel in cs.  output
    // copies values from c to out until c is closed or it receives a value
    // from done, then output calls wg.Done.
    output := func(c <-chan string) {
        for n := range c {
            select {
            case out <- "received " + n:
            case <-done:
            }
        }
        wg.Done()
    }
    wg.Add(len(cs))
    for _, c := range cs {
        go output(c)
    }

    // Start a goroutine to close out once all the output goroutines are
    // done.  This must start after the wg.Add call.
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}
```

See a [complete example in this playground](http://play.golang.org/p/QUEWGlx4-g)

---

Note: whatever solution you will end up using, a good read remains:

[**Principles of designing Go APIs with channels**](https://inconshreveable.com/07-08-2014/principles-of-designing-go-apis-with-channels/) by [Alan Shreve](https://inconshreveable.com/about.html).

In particular:

#### Principle #1

> An **API should declare the directionality of its channels**.